# Why is Heroku not detecting my start script?

Tags: node.js, heroku, package.json

I have a Node.js application on Heroku. To start it, I need `index.js`to be executed. To do that, I added a `package.json` file with a `start` script.

As I read in [Heroku Node.js Support](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/nodejs-support#default-web-process-type):

> First, Heroku looks for a Procfile specifying your process types.
>
> If no Procfile is present in the root directory of your app during the build process, your web process will be started by running npm start, a script you can specify in package.json...

When I define the `start` script to be `node index.js` and I deploy my app to Heroku, I don't see any Dynos in the resources tab.

---

**My code:**

package.json

```
{
    "name": "node.js app",
    "version": "1.4.0",
    "description": "A node.js app.",
    "main": "index.js",
    "repository": {
        "type": "git",
        "url": "Node.js repository"
    },
    "author": "Realex78",
    "license": "MPL-2.0",
    "dependencies": {
        "npm package": "^1.0.0"
    },
    "devDependencies": {
        "npm package": "^1.0.0"
    },
    "scripts": {
        "start": "node index.js",
        "poststart": "node scripts/poststart.js",
        "restart": "node scripts/restart.js"
    }
}
```

Comment: You're missing a quote mark on `repository"`

Comment: @MarkMeyer thanks, I fixed it. (Apparently when editing I removed the quote mark)

Comment: Does `heroku logs` say anything?

Comment: when u deploy to heroku does stdout contain errors?  'heroku logs' should produce some trace.    locally can you 'heroku local' or 'npm run start' to get it to run.

Comment: Did you find any solution? I am also facing same issue.

Answer (score 0):

**Make sure that you aren't using a Procfile, as [Heroku gives it priority](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/deploying-nodejs#specifying-a-start-script) over package.json!**

I.e. even though I had updated my startup script in package.json:

```
  "scripts": {
    "start": "node --harmony server.js"
  },
```

I had forgotten that my Procfile was setup like this:

```
web: node server.js
```

Therefore my startup script in package.json was being ignored!  The fix was to update my Procfile (to in this case include the `--harmony` param).
Note that I did not have to wait 24 hours for a successful deploy; it worked immediately.